# Python, exact matching of list element (string) in another list

Tags: python, regex, list

given a list of first names, I want to find out their full names in another list.

What I have is:

```
group = [ "Calderon Juan", "Bramel Joshua", "Davis Decurious", "Hernandez 
Hilda", "Martinez Francisco", "Dixon Quanzie", "Johnson Landry", "York
Alex", "Mercer Jacob", "Perez Ricardo", "Bowie Emily", "Huber Grayson", 
"Stucker Nicholas", "Cole Christopher", "Caron Michael", "Caronni Vas", 
"Rittenberry Grant"]

people_to_find = ["Caron", "York", "Dixon", "David", "Andrew"]

for s in group:
    for item in people_to_find:
        if item in s:
            print item + ", found in: " + s
```

The output is:

```
Dixon, found in: Dixon Quanzie
York, found in: York Alex
Caron, found in: Caron Michael
Caron, found in: Caronni Vas
```

It is not perfect as it doesn’t do an exact matching. For example,

```
Caron, found in: Caronni Vasly
```

What I want to find out is exactly “Caron”, not any word has a part as “Caron”.

Besides I refind the short list to:

```
people_to_find = ["Caron ", "York ", "Dixon ", "David ", "Andrew "]
```

What would be a good solution?
Thank you.

Comment: `if item in s.split():`

Comment: :) it was marked duplicate before I had a chance :D

Comment: @Tony Tannous, the world is beautiful because of people like you. wish you a great weekend!